# Xcode 6 won't let me develop on my iOS 8 phone

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, xcode6

I was developing an application with iOS 7, and I just updated to the beta of iOS 8. I downloaded Xcode 6 beta and now when I plug my phone in, it lists my phone under "Ineligible devices" and won't let me develop on it. Why is this?

Comment: This question should be re-opened as others, myself included, are having the same issue.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24039010/xcode6-ineligible-devices-section-appeared

Comment: I agree this question should be re-opened. I also had this problem and I have a solution I would like to post:

Restarting my Mac and my iPhone fixed the issue.

Comment: In my case I had to reattach device and when it asks press "Trust this computer", then my device appears available again in xCode

Comment: This question is not too broad.

Comment: This can happen when your device is ahead of the max iOS version for that version of XCode. Upgrade XCode to fix.

Answer (score 11):

I just had the same issue. What fixed it for me was changing the Deployment Target (though in my case i went from 8 to 7).

Comment: Same issue, and that doesn't fix it for me...

Comment: I'm also encountering with this issue

Comment: Didn't work here neither

Comment: I restarted my phone and Mac.  This worked for me.  You should not have to change the deployment target to install your app on an iOS 8 device.

Comment: Also had this issue. Restarting my Macbook was what finally fixed it for me.

Comment: Try this. 
Go to Menu: Product > Destination and select your device. Though it says your device is ineligible, it will still allow you to select it, and building to it will work.

Comment: I unplugged and plugged back in the device and it worked..