# Ineligible Devices section appeared in Xcode 6.x.x

Tags: ios, xcode6

After installing **Xcode 6** my devices moved to greyed-out section **`Ineligible Devices`** and I can't select them as deploy target:

[image]

**Update:**

This error occurs in all versions of `Xcode 6.x.x`.
There are so many different reasons causing this problem

Check this **[solution list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29538173/1698467)**  for more details.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024460/xcode-6-wont-let-me-develop-on-my-ios-8-phone (For whatever reason it will not let me mark as a duplicate)

Comment: In Xcode 5's organizer does the device appear?

Comment: @MZimmerman6 I have tried to warn if NDAs in the past for the likes of iOS7 and I got told to back off by moderators and got told we're not the NDA Police and if Apple have a problem with it they can take it up with the user themselves, so I have just given up warning users about NDAs as there is just no point.

Comment: @Popeye this about iOS 8. My iPhone is still on iOS 7
68cherries, as you see on 2nd screenshot - no.

Comment: @MZimmerman6 Actually, this year there is no NDA so you discuss details. You just can't review it. But thank you for warning. Because I don't think about it before you notice it.

Comment: @skywinder "Further, Apple agrees that You will not be bound by the foregoing confidentiality terms with regard to technical information about pre-release Apple Software and services disclosed by Apple at WWDC (Apple’s Worldwide Developers Conference), except that You may not post screen shots, write public reviews or redistribute any pre-release Apple Software or services." Looks like a screenshot to me. while it is identical to XCode 5, still.

Comment: @MZimmerman6 NDA of what? Anyone pays $99 can get access to Xcode6.  It is not like you were invited to a sealed room and test out next gen ipad.

Comment: @Reed yes you are right to an extent, but you should probably read that agreement you sign when you become a developer. It says quite a bit of what is and is not allowed.

Comment: Stackoverflow cannot get into trouble. If Apple chooses, they can send along a DMCA takedown. It will be taken down, and that's that.

Comment: They can of course subpoena the identities of those posting any questions that infringe and then go after those individuals for damages.

Comment: @Reed: The fact that you pay $99 means not everyone can read Apple's documentation, but only those who paid $99 and agreed to an NDA. If Stackoverflow actually told people not to advice anyone of NDA violations, that's the kind of action that could get them into trouble.

Comment: @gnasher729 ever heard of "unenforceable contract"?  You are very nice to do exactly as the contract says.  But if I broke my contract, it is not that they have a case in the court.  A large number of NDAs out there are either void, voidable or unenforceable.

Comment: None of the solutions below fixing iOS 8.4 on Xcode 6.3.2!

Comment: I found that restarting my iPad resolved the problem.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

*There is a lot of options **(<s>10</s> <s>23</s> 29 answers for this question!)**, that can cause this error. And no one is 100% solve this issue. Here is summarise of all solutions.*

### First of all:

0. **Update to latest Xcode version**
*Most of the reasons, that cause this problem fixed in Xcode version `6.3.1` (6D1002 published April 21, 2015)*

#### List of solutions in order frequency of occurrence:

1. **The most likely solution:**:

   - In Xcode status **go to: `Menu bar`-> `Product` -> `Destination`** and find your device. It will be listed under `Ineligible` section
   - **Select your device**. After you will be able to build and deploy to device! (thanks, [@joshstaiger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29543682/1698467))

   [image]

---

#### If it doesn't work:

2. **iOS Deployment Target** should be `<=` of the version of your device. 
   You find this option in `Build Settings` tab when you click on a target of your project in Xcode.
3. If version is correct - try to **restart Mac and iPhone/iPad simultaneously.** It resolve this issue in most cases! (thanks, [@HoaParis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24039323/1698467))
4. Finally if either doesn't work - try to do this magic actions:

   - switch `iOS Deployment Target` to 8.1
   - restart `Xcode`
   - switch back to desired version.

---

#### Other problems, that cause this issue:

5. `Xcode Beta 6.3` does not support `iOS 8.2` (and also 8.1). You won't see your iDevice in deploy target list. 
   **Use `Xcode 6.2` instead of `Xcode 6.3 beta` in order to debug with an iDevice iOS 8.2**
6. `Xcode 6.3` requires `Unity 4.6.4`
   If you're using an older `Unity` version (e.g. `4.6.3`) you'll always get your devices in the `Ineligible Devices` section (thanks, [@d4rk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29535109/1698467))
7. Also it appears in case of **changing name of Xcode project**. The fix it -  create a new scheme by selecting `Manage Schemes > (+) button`. (thanks, [@dale-moore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26451418/1698467))
8. Beta to Release upgrade of Xcode can require upgrading iOS or watchOS from beta to release version. For example, when switching from Xcode 8 beta 6 to Xcode 8 release, watchOS 3 beta is listed as unsupported.

Comment: None of these worked for me; but @joshtaiger's below did

Comment: If your device has iOS 8.2, the fix for this is to install the 8.2 simulator in Xcode 6.3. Go the Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads. Install the 8.2 simulator under Components. That fixes this.

Comment: Wow.   In Xcode status go to: Menu bar-> Product -> Destination and find your device. It will be listed under Ineligible section  /instead/ of grabbing it from ineligible destinations in general settings does the trick.  Was sure it was a provisioning profile issue.  Thank you.

Comment: It looks like iOS 8.4 isn't supported by XCode 6.3.1? I get the error: `Xcode doesn't support <iphone-name> iOS 8.4 (12H143).` if I try to build, and `<phone-name> may be running a version of iOS that is not supported by this version of Xcode.` if I try to run.

Comment: Looks like this is not working for ios 8.4 - getting Could not find Developer Disk Image with xcode 6.4 + 7.0 beta

Answer (score 493):

**With the release of Xcode 6.3.1, check first the Update 5**

1. **Verify that "iOS Deployment Target" is <= the version of your iDevice.**

[image]

You find this option in "Build Settings" tab when you click on a target of your project in Xcode.

[image]

2. **Then if does not work, try to restart Xcode. Sometimes we have to restart the Mac and iPhone/iPad. Take a look at the Updates below before restarting Xcode**
3. **Update: in Yosemite, Xcode 6.0.1 does not support iOS 8.1, you have to update to Xcode 6.1 if you want to debug on iOS 8.1 device, or you will probably have the same problem as described in the topic**
4. **Update 2:** Xcode Beta 6.3 does not support iOS 8.2 (and also 8.1 - thanks @steveb). You won't see your device in deploy target list. I don't know if other versions are supported.
5. **Update 3.** Use Xcode 6.2 instead of Xcode 6.3 beta in order to debug with a device running iOS 8.2
6. **Updated 4 :** **for Xcode 6.3** (and eventually 6.3 beta if someone use it :) ), if you have this problem, just go to Product > Destination to select your device. Even though it says your device is ineligible, it will still allow you to select it. If your device version is >= target version, the build should work. It must be a bug for Xcode 6.3 in debug with iOS 8.3 (or maybe other iOS version) (thanks @einfach).

[image]

7. **Update 5:** Apple released Xcode 6.3.1 that fix the issue of ineligible device. If you have this problem with Xcode 6.3, upgrade to XCode 6.3.1

From Release Notes (Xcode 6.3.1):

> Fixed: Devices previously listed as "ineligible for running”
>   erroneously are listed correctly. (20121178)

Comment: I update my question. "iOS Deployment Target" still 7.0.

Comment: FYI: I only had to restart Xcode, did not have to restart the device.  Thankfully, it was a coworker's device and I didn't have the passcode, LOL!

Comment: +1 for Update 2.  Device on iOS 8.1 doesn't work with XCode Beta 6.3 (your post has a typo, it's not v8.3).

Comment: From the [Xcode 6.3 Beta 2 release notes:](http://adcdownload.apple.com//Developer_Tools/Xcode_6.3_beta_2/Xcode_6.3_beta_2_Release_Notes.pdf) "Devices running iOS 8.2 is not supported in Xcode 6.3 beta 2"

Comment: What finally worked for me was setting the Deployment target in the Project view, "Info" panel. Nothing else did it. (Xcode 6.3 beta 3)

Comment: just updated Xcode to 6.3 and iOS to 8.3... this bug shows up only on iPhone device not iPad.  Use the Product > Destination (Updated 4 ) above will work for now.

Comment: It seems to be a bug with XCode 6.3 and iOS8.3 only.

Comment: This is the second time this answer helps me

Comment: Had the same problem with Xcode 6.3 and iOS 8.3, this answer solved my issue. Thanks a lot, I've been struggling with this for hours :)

Comment: "Updated 4 : for XCode 6.3 & iOS 8.3" was what saved me. Amazing. Thanks!

Comment: Just adding to the list of possible iOS/device issues - I've had the same issue with an iOS 7 iPad device with deployment target at 5.0 on Xcode 6.3 which can also be worked around with update 4

Comment: Yes, I believe that this bug in XCode 6.3 produces in many iOS versions, not only 8.3

Comment: Whilst this issue persists, the solution: Product->Destination->TheDevice can be done via keyboard with the shortcut for Product->Destination->Select Next Destination **⌃⌥⌘]** or Select Previous Destination **⌃⌥⌘[** Faster and less frustrating.

Comment: I had this problem when Xcode 6.3 wouldn't let me run a Unity-deployed iOS App on an iPhone 4s. Fixed the deployment target but the iPhone still showed up in the 'Ineligible Devices' section. Your solution 6. helped me with this, so thanks a lot!!

Comment: Did they work for anyone who is still running OSX 10.9?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have OSX 10.9. Which XCode and iOS version do you have?

Comment: for me the deployment target had to be exactly the version of the device - 8.2 :/

Comment: I had to plug in two devices. (this is for Xcode 6.3) One device is still on 8.2 and the other is 8.3. The device with 8.3 is the one I would like to develop on and is the device in the ineligible category. With both plugged in I set the deployment target to 8.3, which moved the 8.2 device into the ineligible category and forced the 8.3 device to be selected. After this I changed the deployment target back to 7.0 and both devices stayed available. It's the only way that works for me currently.

Comment: Same problem, but fixed it by selecting an appropriate provisioning profile, i.e. one that add my device known by the provisioning. Looks like XCode 6.3 is checking before compilation if the device will be able to receive the app.

Comment: XCode 6.3.1 does not fix the problem... I always have the same issue. :/

Comment: I don't have that error with my XCode 6.3.1. If you have always the issue, just try the Update 4 solution above.

Comment: Solved: The Xcode 6.3.1 update seems to have fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Looks like Xcode 7 beta 2 has the same problem with iOS 8.4 release build, refuses to recognise the device as 'unavailable' and 'Could not find developer disk image'

Comment: Because XCode 7 beta 2 does not support iOS 8.4. You can find this information in the release notes. link: http://adcdownload.apple.com/WWDC_2015/Xcode_7_beta/Xcode_7_beta_Release_Notes.pdf. With iOS 8.4, you can use your XCode 6 and update it to 6.4

Answer (score 100):

Everyone should note that there seems to be a bug in XCode 6.3 (Beta and GM) that is aggravating this problem.

I have iOS 8.3 installed on my device.  Setting the build target to iOS <= 8.3 did not help.  Nor did any of the other solutions posted.

What worked for me:

Go to the Product Menu > Destination and select your device.  It will be listed under "Ineligible", but you will still be able to select it.  After doing this, I was able to build and deploy to my device.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Sir you saved me lots of time! Thank you!

Comment: I had this problem upon upgrading to XCode 6.3 (7.1 Deployment;  8.2 and 8.3 iPhones; 8.2 iPad worked fine). This answer worked for me with no problems, except that it's still marked as "ineligible", so I have to go to Product>Destination whenever I switch to one of these.

Comment: @mackworth Once I set an Ineligible Devices to Destination and set iOS 7.0 to the deployment target, this issue disappeared. After that, the ineligible list was not shown up again at least to me :)

Comment: After a couple times having to use it, eventually the ineligible list disappeared for me as well. Apparently Xcode tired of the game.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround -- Apple stuff isn't as rock solid as it used to be.

Comment: Worked for me as well

Comment: Worked for me as well, however now my Xcode freezes up whenever I select the device menu ([Build Name] -> Alex's iPhone). Hopefully a fix is coming soon. The destination menu still works, so it's not a stopper.

Comment: I found a workaround was to open an earlier (saved) version of the same project, then close it and re-open the latest version. Yecch! However.. this solution also works, and seems a lot better. However, there sure are plenty more issues with 6.3, e.g. provisioning for WatckKit. (Separate topic.)

Answer (score 16):

I had a similar issue and for me I had upgraded to iOS8 and also changed the name of my Xcode project.  The fix for me was to create a new scheme by selecting Manage Schemes > (+) button.

After doing this, my list of devices returned.

Comment: Thanks. Simply deleting the scheme and creating a new one worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me too. The problem did start after I renamed the project, now it's gone.

Comment: Worked for me too. Project rename aswell.

Comment: It's possible that what fixed it was the fact Executable in the Run section is now set, i.e. http://imgur.com/qnX7kc0

Answer (score 13):

What worked for me is to install XCode 6.1 (compatible with iOS 8.1)

Answer (score 7):

Besides setting iOS Deployment Target to iOS 8.0, also **restart your iOS8 iPhone/iPad**. This did the trick for me.

Answer (score 6):

You can try below solutions to run build in your device.

1. Restart your iOS device (If device is recently updated) and your Xcode.
2. Make Sure that in build settings "iOS Deployment Target" is <= the version of your iDevice.
   [image]

Otherwise you can goto - Product > Destination, select your device which would be showing as ineligible device.You will be able to select your device and run your build.

I also came across that if you have the iOS 8.4 then your Xcode doesn't have the SDK for iOS 8.4 due to which devices show as ineligible. To solve this issue

Download Xcode 6.4

Answer (score 4):

My iPhone has updated to iOS8.1. My Xcode version is 6.0.1, and my mac os version is 10.10. When I want to run app in my iPhone, there is a section named `Ineligible Devices(OS Version)`. Then I update Xcode to 6.1 version, solved problem.

Part of Xcode 6.1 release note: `Includes SDKS for OS X 10.10 Yosemite, OS X 10.9 Mavericks, and iOS 8.1`.

That is, Xcode 6.0.x don't support iOS 8.1.

Answer (score 4):

My solution was that I had recently upgraded my iOS device to 8.3 and Xcode still didn't recognize it. The fix was to simply upgrade Xcode to 6.3 :)

Answer (score 3):

After trying the 2 answers above (changing deployment target and restarting my iOS device), what finally fixed it for me was restarting my Mac.

Comment: me too - restarted ipad and mac and all is well.

Answer (score 3):

For iOS 9.1+ devices, the Xcode version should be upgraded to 7.1 (even 7.0x will not work)

Answer (score 2):

I simply restarted my Mac and my iPhone 6 and the problem was solved. I never had to change my deployment target.

Answer (score 2):

Changing your deployment target is not a good idea to solve this problem (it will change which iOS versions you support on the app store).

What I did is restart just Xcode and it was fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with txulu, changing the deployment target is a ridiculous idea. I need to support devices back at least one version, that is non-negotiable to me.

Restarting my iPhone 5 after updating to iOS 8.1 and Xcode to 6.1 worked for me.

Comment: updating to iOS 8.1 is also not the right way to solve the problem. All you have to do is change to iOS8, then back and restart all.

Comment: I just mentioned what I did to solve it. iOS 8.1 is probably not necessary nor is XCode 6.1.  I just made sure I was on the latest iOS and XCode releases and then restarted my device.

Answer (score 2):

Simply  **deploying to another device** and then **switching back** to the former 'ineligible' device worked here.
(saved the hassle of restarting anything)

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had to reattach device and when it asks press "Trust this computer", then my device appears available again in xCode

Answer (score 2):

make sure the deployment target version in setting is lower or equal than the iphone version

if the deployment target is 7.1  but the iphone is 7.0.3

you will see that error message

Answer (score 2):

Ran into the same issue, using `Unity3D`

**=> `Xcode 6.3` requires `Unity 4.6.4`**

If you're using an older `Unity` version (e.g. `4.6.3`) you'll always get your devices in the `Ineligible Devices` section

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade XCode to ensure that it supports your current iOS version on device.

(In my case, my phone was on iOS 9.1.x) `but XCode version was 7, which supported iOS 9.0 devices)

Answer (score 1):

I changed my deployment target to 7.1 the same as my iphone, and now I can run swift programs on it. It was on 8.0 and showed up as ineligible.

Answer (score 1):

I set my "iOS Deployment Target" in "Project" and "Targets" from 7.1 to 8.0 and restarted Xcode (with "Quit") and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that the answer it to upgrade Xcode to 6.1. If you are using Xcode 6.0.x you will not be able to select a device running 8.1. Your deployment targets and OS version should have nothing to do with this.

If your OS version is greater than 10.9.4 I would recommend this. First, un-attaching all devices. Download [Xcode 6.1](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/). After opening the new version of Xcode attach your device. You should be good to go.

Another good thing would be to look at the [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc6_release_notes.html). It's and easy read and gives you a general idea of what still needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

My iPad was 8.0, but i had deployment target set to 8.1. I changed the deployment target in build settings, and immediately, the ipad moved out of the "ineligible" category. (I am on Yosemite and XCode 6.1)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the 6.3 Xcode Beta. I had the same issue as above. I restarted my computer and phone but did not work. Simply went to the build target under build settings and changed build target to 8.1. I hope this is fixed in the next released. Make sure that after you change your build setting - you need to restart your device and Xcode!

Answer (score 1):

Please check you device iOS version and your Xcode application build target version. This might be causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

My answer, perhaps listed already but i did not notice, was simple: I deleted the app in question from the target itself, then fired up Xcode and the target was then available. And yes, i tried most of the other suggestions, and was resorting to activating the target from the Product menu, but that was getting tedious.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a chance to run any project on the 'ineligible' device from other Mac with Xcode, try it and then reconnect the device to your Mac (without restarting Xcode/Mac).
For me, after doing that, the 'ineligible device' section disappears and my device returns to the normal status.
Hope it helps for someone.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed in Xcode version 6.3.1 (6D1002) published April 21, 2015.

At least the problem magically went away for me after installing this Xcode version.

Answer (score 1):

Tried all possible Updates, with Xcode 6.3, iOS 8.3 and OSX 10.10.3, but didn't got a permanent solution.

Kudos to skywinder,the first option worked!

Answer (score 1):

For most people the cause of the problem is probably mismatch between Xcode, device version and app target version.
If versions are not a problem for you, most likely is that the device (iPhone/iPad) has been used with another Mac to copy apps to. This happens particularly more with a team environment where an iDevice can be used between team members. Xcode knows some other developer's Mac has connected to this device, it will show up as "Ineligible". But the previous Mac that connected to it, it will show up as normal.
The quickest work around is as shown by joshstaiger among others:
Go to Xcode ->Product->Destination
Select the ineligible device as target. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

The most common cause for this issue is Xcode 6.3 and running iOS 8.2 on your device. Xcode 6.3 doesn't install the 8.2 simulator by default. It has the 8.3 simulator installed.

The solution by @joshstaiger works, but it is not a permanent fix. You have to do this each time you want to run the app on your device

The permanent fix is to simply install the 8.2 simulator in Xcode 6.3. Go the Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads. Install the 8.2 simulator under Components.

Now you will no longer see your device listed under ineligible devices.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following useful:

1. Connect to the new device, go to itunes, make sure you sync the
   device (you might have a certificate issue)
2. Follow NateJC's advice (i.e. switch devices and switch back again)