# Error running playground. Unable to find suitable target device. (iOS Swift)

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6, swift-playground

I created a new project in XCode.

File > New > Playground (option+shift+cmd+N)

[image]

I restarted my XCode and also rebooted my system, but still same error.

Comment: Verify device in for your target in Xcode, Next to scheme Name. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24039010/xcode6-ineligible-devices-section-appeared/24039323#24039323

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try navigating to the Xcode Menu
Window >> devices (shift+cmd+2) a new window will pop up.

On the bottom left, add a new simulator, specifically one running on iOS 8.0 to the existing list.

Restart Xcode.

Answer (score 22):

From the developer forums, this worked for me:

> 1. Quit Xcode
> 2. Delete the folder `/Users/<username>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices`. For example, in Terminal: `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices`
> 3. In Terminal: `killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService` (or just reboot).

Comment: Note: in my case, when ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices was empty, the next launch of Xcode 7 auto-generated all possible device and iOS combinations based on the SDKs present on the system.  Subsequently, the error went away, but i still don't know which particular simulator is the "Choosen Required One".

Comment: Thanks. Took me a while to find this solution.

Answer (score 9):

Fox Xcode 7, I had to install iPad Air or iPad Air 2 for the playground to work.

Comment: Thanks! Most easiest way to solve the bug without need of iOS8.

Answer (score 9):

Another possible way to encounter that issue is to get Xcode being auto-updated, while the simulator was launched.

The solution is like mentioned above but more polite:

1. Quit Xcode and Simulator app
2. Run in Terminal: **killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService**
3. Launch Xcode and find that all fixed now.

Sure, you can just reboot instead.

Answer (score 1):

As referred by @Mayank Gupta , It worked on adding new simulator and restarting the XCode.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You forgot to put a black spot over playground name.