# iOS/tvOS playground fails with "Unable to find execution service for selected run destination"

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-playground

After migrating to XCode 7.1 I can not use playground with iOS and tvOS platforms.  Only OS X works.  Simplest playground code produces error message:

> Unable to find execution service for selected run destination

I suspect it has to do with XCode not finding the right simulator, however I have no idea where and how to configure it.

I tried playground in the existing project, as well as just newly created one from the splash screen.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

**UPDATE:**

Checking console gives a bit more insight, but still not clear how to fix:

```
24/10/2015 10:16:10,193 lsd[279]: LaunchServices: Could not store lsd-identifiers file at /private/var/db/lsd/com.apple.lsdschemes.plist
24/10/2015 10:16:10,212 com.apple.usbmuxd[82]: LOCKDOWN_V2_BONJOUR_SERVICE_NAME is _apple-mobdev2._tcp,8de107c0
24/10/2015 10:16:10,248 Xcode[819]:  DeveloperPortal: Using pre-existing current store at URL (file:///Users/courteouselk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DeveloperPortal%207.1.db).
24/10/2015 10:16:10,381 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService[461]: Requested phone is is not available for pairing.  Assuming it has the capability.
24/10/2015 10:16:10,384 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService[461]: Requested phone is is not available for pairing.  Assuming it has the capability.
24/10/2015 10:16:12,929 com.apple.usbmuxd[82]: _SendAttachNotification Device 80:ea:96:04:a5:da@fe80::82ea:96ff:fe04:a5da._apple-mobdev2._tcp.local. has already appeared on interface 4. Suppressing duplicate attach notification.
24/10/2015 10:16:13,311 GPUToolsAgent[832]: Mac Agent inited !!!
24/10/2015 10:16:14,287 Xcode[819]: <DYMobileDevice: 0x7ffbfd6b6320>: failed to acquire service transport reservation: Error Domain=DYAMDErrorDomain Code=-402653150 "(null)"
24/10/2015 10:16:14,447 Xcode[819]: [MT] IDEPlaygroundEditor: Error encountered attempting to run playground: Error Domain=IDEPlaygroundErrorDomain Code=1 "Unable to find execution service for selected run destination." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to find execution service for selected run destination.}
24/10/2015 10:16:19,672 mdworker[255]: LaunchServices: received XPC_ERROR_CONNECTION_INTERRUPTED trying to map database
24/10/2015 10:16:19,672 mdworker[255]: LaunchServices: Database mapping failed with result -10822, retrying
24/10/2015 10:16:19,672 mdworker[255]: LaunchServices: received XPC_ERROR_CONNECTION_INTERRUPTED trying to map database
24/10/2015 10:16:19,673 mdworker[255]: LaunchServices: received XPC_ERROR_CONNECTION_INTERRUPTED trying to map database
24/10/2015 10:16:19,673 mdworker[255]: LaunchServices: Database mapping failed with result -10822, retrying
24/10/2015 10:16:19,673 mdworker[255]: LaunchServices: received XPC_ERROR_CONNECTION_INTERRUPTED trying to map database
24/10/2015 10:16:19,674 mdworker[255]: LaunchServices: received XPC_ERROR_CONNECTION_INTERRUPTED trying to map database
24/10/2015 10:16:19,674 mdworker[255]: LaunchServices: Database mapping failed with result -10822, retrying
24/10/2015 10:16:19,674 mdworker[255]: LaunchServices: received XPC_ERROR_CONNECTION_INTERRUPTED trying to map database
24/10/2015 10:16:19,674 mdworker[255]: LaunchServices: received XPC_ERROR_CONNECTION_INTERRUPTED trying to map database
24/10/2015 10:16:19,674 mdworker[255]: LaunchServices: Database mapping failed with result -10822, retrying
24/10/2015 10:16:19,675 mdworker[255]: LaunchServices: received XPC_ERROR_CONNECTION_INTERRUPTED trying to map database
24/10/2015 10:16:20,497 Xcode[819]: CompanionProxy: _SocketReadCallback:128 (0x0x700000117000): Failed to receive response from AMDevice 0x7ffbfe60cad0 {UDID = e4bfce5e11be0bcf730ada45b4d6ae81f1abdb01, device ID = 23, FullServiceName = 80:ea:96:04:a5:da@fe80::82ea:96ff:fe04:a5da._apple-mobdev2._tcp.local.}: 0xe8000084
24/10/2015 10:16:20,497 Xcode[819]: CompanionProxy: _SocketReadCallback:200 (0x0x700000117000): Stopped listening for paired devices from AMDevice 0x7ffbfe60cad0 {UDID = e4bfce5e11be0bcf730ada45b4d6ae81f1abdb01, device ID = 23, FullServiceName = 80:ea:96:04:a5:da@fe80::82ea:96ff:fe04:a5da._apple-mobdev2._tcp.local.}: 0xe8000084
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ok, after some struggle, here's the solution.

1. Clean up the folder `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator`
2. Restart the machine
3. Try running an iOS Playground, it should work without problems now.

**Note:** In my case I renamed `CoreSimulator` to `CoreSimulator.old`, and after restart a new `CoreSimulator` was auto-created (so, I just threw away the `.old` one).

BTW, there is a file `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/device_set.plist` with whole list of Simulators under `/Root/DefaultDevices`.  I think this is where the problem was coming from.

Comment: I was able to do this without the drastic "restart the machine" by using Activity Monitor to kill (force quit) the com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService process while Xcode and the iOS Simulator were not running.

Comment: This worked but it also resets and puts all the simulators back as well. Hopefully deleting all of the sims again except for current iPhone won't cause the issue to come back.

Comment: I did it this way and it did not work however, while having playground open I went      window>devices and in the left hand column right-clicked and deleted the simulators that way.  Worked!!!  Same concept different approach.

Answer (score 69):

There may be a faster solution:

Check that you have **iPad Pro simulator** in your devices in Xcode. If not – add it via Add Simulator option.

As some have noted in comments, you may also need to restart Xcode or reopen the playground.

To add a simulator go to Devices (Window > Devices). Click the + button at the far bottom left of the window, click "Add Simulator", then select the appropriate "Device Type" from the dropdown and click "Create".

Comment: Did not require restart for me on Xcode 7.1; just created a new Playground under iOS Platform and it works! (though it took 20-30 seconds to show the first output)

Comment: @alexander-borisenko, for my own understanding, how did you know installing that specific simulator would fix the issue?

Comment: Worked for me too (no Xcode restart required — just closed and re-opened the playground).

Comment: You saved my life (just need to reopen the playground)

Comment: I can't believe that this helped. Really Apple??

Comment: Worked for me as well. Thank you

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer. Duping this radar might speed along fixing this issue: http://www.openradar.me/23719213

Answer (score 20):

I was able to resolve this issue with these two commands in the Terminal:

```
$ rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices
$ killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService
```

Answer (score 2):

Delete everything inside your DerivedData folder, ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData, and then restart Xcode

Comment: Did that.  Does not help.

Comment: You were close, btw.  Folder to clean was `CoreSimulator`, see my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add all the  simulators in xcode--> window-->devices.

and restart the xcode it will works fine

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 8 update. Ran into a similar message

"selected platform is not available"

With the playground open, in the upper right of the window, the last icon on the right: Hide or Show the Utilities. Click that, then in that area click the icon on the left: Show File Inspector.

Then in the Playground Settings popup it may be set for unknown. Change it to your Platform of choice (OS X for me) then you should be good to go.