# Iphone4 development device xcode6

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, iphone-4

I have just started developing iOS apps with xCode 6.3. I only have 1 physical device with me, an iPhone 4 (no S). In order to work with Push notifications I need to register at least one device for development but xCode sees my iPhone4 as ineligible device (it runs IOS 7.1.2). I tried adjusting the building target to 7.1, restarting the device and the mac, but nothing has worked.

is there any way I can register the iPhone4 as development device without buying a new iOS device?

Comment: Make sure in you have the device registered in your developers account and have proper provisioning profile setup for the app.

Comment: Xcode also tells you you have an "ineligible device" device if it is still collecting symbols from it. I don't know if that is the issue here, but I saw it before.

Comment: @ Prajeet Shrestha Not a proper comment because he has issue not detected device in Xcode  it is not need  provisioning profile.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ineligible Devices section appeared in Xcode 6.x.x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24039010/ineligible-devices-section-appeared-in-xcode-6-x-x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was actually very stupid. I had tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29538173/1698467) but I didn't clean and rebuild the project. After a clean, rebuild and restart (!!!) I can now run the apps on a Physical iPhone4

Comment: Yeah, restarts are unfortunately very useful in debugging Xcode problems. I've found that when the provisioning profile doesn't get chosen correctly (when signing builds after changing info.plist), restarting helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try to download Xcode 5.1.1 from
https://developer.apple.com/downloads/

It's based on iOS 7.1 SDK. It should work with your iPhone4.

Answer (score 0):

your device not detected Xcode 6.0 because hardware requrement not match. you must check it iPhones 4s or above. Also Xcode 6 not detect our iPhone.

Answer (score -1):

there is no problem with your device.you can test with this device.follow these steps i hope u will get your problem solved.

1.remove device from xcode from window>device.

2. now link iphone and press trust from iphone when it asks to trust.

3.Keep your target sdk version 7.0 or 7.1.

now run your project.

Comment: @Dharmendara chaudhari not exact ans. be give specific.

Comment: Bro,I mean to say first remove your device from Xcode if in case it is shown dere in organiser.

Comment: @ Dharmendra They want to use iPhone 4 in Xcode 6 or above so not a valid ans. Please write a specific solution

Comment: @annu..I am myself using iphone4 with Xcode 6.1 and it gets connected easily.hete he was not able to,so maybe he would have tried before symbol files dond reading or may be pressed untrust.so for fresh start he have to remove device from organiser,and then connect to Xcode,iPhone will asked to trust,and on pressing trust it will connect.

Comment: still you does not make sense, Why he Press untrusted in dialog? actually  he want to connect now device in Xcode.

Comment: @annu..if he correctly set deployment target above or equals to his device iOS version,den only reason left not showing device is what I said.sometimes we did silly mistake ,not blunders like u doing posting again n again and showing as if u know him,and as if we didn't do ol this with his iPhone e but with u.