# iPhone running iOS 8.3 shows up as ineligible in Xcode 6.2

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Current setup:

- iPhone 6+ updated to iOS 8.2
- iMac running Mavericks (10.9) with Xcode 6.2
- Deployment target set to 8.2

When I connect the iPhone, it shows up as ineligible.

Also, it shows this warning:

[image]

I've tried:

- to reboot both iPhone & iMac -> Not solved
- to manually select iPhone from: `Product > Destination > Ineligible Devices`

Many other answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24039010/xcode6-ineligible-devices-section-appeared), but all for problems using Xcode 6.3, not 6.2.

I know I can solve this:

- upgrading to Yosemite & installing Xcode 6.3
- using an iPhone running 8.2

But is there any possibility that mounting the Xcode 6.3 DMG and copying some libs / symlinking something it will work?

Comment: Not yet. Haven't tried copying libs. Will post here if successul

Comment: I tried step 6 in the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24039323/2382712 but it did not work for me as I still running OSX Mavericks

Comment: got the same problem, looking forward for your results

Answer (score 11):

Just copy the folder `DeviceSupport/8.3` from Xcode 6.3 to Xcode 6.2.

Details:

- Download Xcode 6.2 and 6.3, install as `/Applications/Xcode_6.2.app` and `/Applications/Xcode_6.3.app` (or similar names)
- In both installations, there's a folder `Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport`
- In Xcode 6.2, this folder contains packages for iOS 8.2 and many lower versions, but not for 8.3.
- In Xcode 6.3, this folder also contains a package for iOS 8.3. In my case, the folder is called `8.3 (12F69)`
- Copy the iOS 8.3 package from Xcode 6.3 to Xcode 6.2 (this command is one line, of course):

`cp -r '/Applications/Xcode_6.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/8.3 (12F69)' '/Applications/Xcode_6.2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport'`

- Or even better, create a link:

`ln -s '/Applications/Xcode_6.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/8.3 (12F69)' '/Applications/Xcode_6.2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport'`

- Now restart Xcode 6.2 and connect your device through USB. Xcode should allow you to test apps on it.

Diego Freniche's solution (copying the whole `iPhoneOS.platform` folder) was a great help, but when I ran my app from Xcode 6.2, it looked slightly different than it did when I deployed an ipa file on the phone (buttons in wrong positions, status bar display wrong). I guess Xcode got confused and built the app as if it was targeted at a different iOS version.

With this solution (only copy one folder in `DeviceSupport`), it looks like the app works exactly as it is supposed to. I'll let you know if I encounter problems, but I haven't seen any so far.

Comment: Works for me: OS X Maverick, XCode 6.2, iPhone iOS 8.3. Just copy the folders in the DeviceSupport folder, and it works. But I don't know if there are further issue.

Comment: Worked for me on Maverick. Since Yoesmite does not run well on my VM, this is the only way left.

Answer (score 10):

A little progress, but this is a **WIP**.

**Looks like in Yosemite Xcode 6.2 works correctly with 8.3 devices. Need to test on Mavericks**

Testing with Xcode 6.2 in Yosemite (need to test also in Mavericks, any feedback would be appreciated)

- Go to your Xcode 6.2 folder and rename

> /Applications/Xcode-6.2 copia.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform

into

> /Applications/Xcode-6.2 copia.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform.old

- Mount your Xcode 6.3 DMG, install it
- Copy from Xcode 6.3 this folder:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform

inside your Xcode 6.2 folder.

- you'll probably find an error telling you `root`user does not own the simulator / OS Platform folder. To solve that just open Terminal, then:

  `$ cd /Applications/Xcode6.2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms`

  `$ sudo chown -R root iPhoneSimulator.platform/`

  `$ sudo chown -R root iPhoneOS.platform/`
- now you can run your app inside your iOS 8.3 device from Xcode 6.2 **but you have no simulators in the target tdestination menu**

**UPDATE**: I'm getting weird errors while `ibtool` tries to compile the storyboards:

> /Users/dfreniche/Desktop/Test/Test/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.InterfaceBuilder error 2001.)

So **finally give up and update to Yosemite**. If there's any new info on this, please share.

Comment: I've just try it, it works and I am also able to use all simulators as without this hack, will try to use it for several days just to understand how stable it is

Comment: Thank you -- I am experiencing crashing on Yosemite with this -- but, as a workaround, doing this once, and then restoring the 6.2 iPhoneOS.platform folder seems to work.  If I restart my device I'm going to guess that it will revert back to the prior behavior where it will not let me run it.

Comment: Crashes for me with 10.9.5 and Xcode 6.2. I tried the platforms folder from both 6.3 and 6.3.1. Wish it worked for me...

Comment: Thanks for the instructions! They're working for me. I'm on Mavericks. Just downloaded Xcode 6.3 from developer.apple.com. When I try to open it, I get the message that it needs Yosemite, but I don't care - I copy iPhoneOS.platform to my Xcode 6.2 installation, start Xcode 6.2, and now I can run my app on my iOS 8.3 iPhone 4s. Thanks! (P.S.: I don't want to upgrade to Yosemite because I want to use the iOS 6 simulator in Xcode 5.)

Comment: Even Xcode 5.0 can run apps on my 8.3 phone now, although I didn't even change anything in the Xcode 5.0 installation. Maybe because Xcode 6.2 created ```~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/8.3 (12F70)``` when I plugged in my phone...

Comment: In my case, the simulators didn't change. They're are still available: iOS 6.0, 6.1 and 7.0 in Xcode 5.0, 7.1, 8.1 and 8.2 in Xcode 6.2.

Comment: There are a few quirks though: 1. Xcode 5 can only handle the 8.3 phone when I start it *after* Xcode 6 has run. 2. When I run the app through Xcode 6 on the phone, there are a few subtle layout changes. Looks like Xcode 6 makes the app look like it would on iOS 6 or so.

Comment: This worked for me - I have Xcode 6.2 on Mavericks, and when I followed the procedure above, my IOS 8.2 device can run my app.  Yay - thanks!

Comment: I found a way that is less intrusive and works better for me. See my answer.

Comment: Obviously if you're on Mavericks you can't install xcode 6.3 so just mount the installation dmg and navigate to the paths mentioned above after doing  "show package contents" on the uninstallable xcode6.3 application. Hope that helps. I'm on 10.9.5 using Xcode Version 6.2 and everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with connecting iOS8.3 devices to Xcode 6.2 on Mavericks. Ok on a machine at work running Xcode 6.4 on Yosemite. Software update on the Mavericks machine doesn't offer any higher version. Looking at the specs of Xcode 6.4 (and presumably 6.3 of the original question) says it requires OS X 10.10 (i.e. Yosemite). So, whether or not you can hack around it, the behaviour you/we are seeing on Mavericks is what Apple intends.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and I don't want to just use the lastest version of XCode for the need of maintaining my old projects. I end up with installing two versions XCode(6.2 and 6.3) to solve this problem. Here is what I did.

1. Download XCode6.2 install package from apple site
2. Upgrade the existed XCode6.2 to x6.3
3. Open my project on XCode6.3 (this time the device can be recognized by XCode, and I think XCode6.3 might have done some updates to your project.)
4. Close my project, re-install XCode6.2, there will be a prompt saying I have a newer version and if I want to keep both. Click Yes. Then I have two versions of XCode.

After all those steps done, I can finally open my project and use my device in XCode6.2. Hopefully it can help someone.

Answer (score -3):

XCODE 6.3 is out.. It solved my problem.. If you have Yosemite, you can download the 6.4 beta version

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. I've already stated that I can do that. The problem is when you can't do that, are on 10.9, using Xcode 6.2 but your phone is on 8.3