# XCODE 6.2 inelligible device IOS 8.3

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode6, ios8.3

i got error msg while i try to RUN code in XCODE 6.2..
Suggest me Solution.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When this type of Issue occurs at that time,

you have to Download Latest Version of **XCODE**,

in my case i have to download **XCODE 6.3 beta Version**, so i can RUN in **iPhone 8.3 OS**.
it's perfect Solution.

**Download** Latest XCODE from LINK : https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/

Comment: It's not the perfect solution. But it is the requirement. Without that you can't do anything.

Comment: did you have other solution ?, i found this one, if u have then tell us, we will appreciate it Gentleman.

Comment: You have to install the Latest Xcode 6.3 update. The XCode 6.2 does't support iOS 8.3.

Comment: That i want to say, this is not the solu., everyone knows that you have to upgrade your Xcode

Comment: @iOSDeveloper,  from my point of view, its perfect answer.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/29727982/1050482 -- this might work for those who cannot yet go to Yosemite.

Comment: @PaulCezanne, yes defiantly its depend on OS .