# Can't install builds via TestFlight as of Xcode 6.3 build 6d570

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios8, xcode6.3

I'm archiving my builds like normal, selecting iOS device from the device menu, and clicking Product->Archive. Once the archiving finishes, I click "Submit to App Store" in the Organizer window.

After the app successfully uploads to iTunes Connect, I enable TestFlight beta testing and try to download it to my device, at which point I get an error message:

> **Unable to Download Apps**
>
> "[Your app] and 1 other application could not be installed at this time.
>
> Done | Retry

Any ideas what's going on here? I also tried running the debugger on my device, which is now listed as an "ineligible device" in XCode, even though it's running 8.3 and my deployment target is 7.0.

Comment: I have the same problem after switching to Xcode 6.3. Did you manage to fix it?

Comment: @LucWollants I did, but it was a matter of updating the build number and uploading a new build to iTunes Connect.

Comment: I had some time to test it again and I also had to make a new build with a new version and a new upload. After this new build the orange dot finally showed next to the application name to indicate it is a beta build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by updating the version number in my info.plist file and rebuilding.

Answer (score 0):

This is may be related to this thread, Try this => [Ineligible Devices section appeared in Xcode 6.x.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24039010/xcode6-ineligible-devices-section-appeared)

```
Updated 4 : for XCode 6.3 & iOS 8.3, if you have this problem, just go to Product > Destination to select your device. Even though it says your device is ineligible, it will still allow you to select it. If your iDevice version is >= target version, the build should work. It must be a bug for XCode 6.3 in debug with iOS 8.3 (thanks @einfach)
```