# Xcode 6.3 showing Ineligible Device

Tags: ipad, xcode6, xcode6.3

I'm using latest `Xcode` i.e. 6.3 and my devices(iPad Mini) having `iOS ver 8.3(12F69)`. I'm not able test my app with this device as its showing *Ineligible Devices*. See the attached screenshot from *xcode*.

I'm not sure why this is happening, using latest Xcode
[image]

[image]

Comment: And what's the iOS version of NGA iPad Mini ?

Comment: Go to Product > Destination, and even though it says your device is ineligible, it will still allow you to select it, then building to it will work.

Comment: I've already mention it there. Its 8.3 build 12F69

Comment: Thanks @Manthan it works. I can run the application now. But any Idea why it is showing ineligible?

Comment: @AmitSingh: Apple's updates are not perfect. They have some weird bugs so we have to deal with this. I have posted it as an answer. Please accept.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Go to **Product** > **Destination**, and even though it says your device is ineligible, it will still allow you to select it, then building to it will work.

There are some bugs in apple's release sometimes, but we have no option to find a solution that works for us.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Is it possible that my app is for iPhone and I'm trying to test it on iPad, that is why its showing Ineligible Devices. I'm pretty sure that in the previous xcode this was not the case. I'm just guessing, Is it?

Comment: @AmitSingh: No. I don't think so... It is a bug in xCode 6.3. You can read it here also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24039010/ineligible-devices-section-appeared-in-xcode-6-x-x

Comment: `The Developer Disk Image could not be mounted.`

Comment: I get `Could not find Developer Disk image` in XCode 7

Comment: @Alexander did you find anything??? I had a same alert and not running on selected device Xcode 7

Comment: @El Captain, no I started testing with the iOS Simulator only. I suspect that the SDK is just too new for the device in question.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not able to select your device you can try below set of solution:
1. Restart your iOS device (If device is recently updated)

2. Restart the Xcode, most probably this should fix the issue.
3. Otherwise you can goto - Product > Destination, select your device which would be showing as ineligible device.You will be able to select your device and go ahead with the build.

also i have observed that if you have the iOS 8.4 then your Xcode doesn't have the SDK for iOS 8.4 due to which devices show as ineligible.
To solve this issue

**Download Xcode 6.4**

Answer (score 1):

I did reset XCode from command line by running following commands (then restart XCode) and device started appearing for me correctly:

```
defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode
rm -rf $HOME/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode
rm -rf $HOME/Library/Saved\ Application\ State/com.apple.dt.Xcode.savedState
rm -rf $HOME/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.*
```

Answer (score 1):

Close and restart Xcode worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [changelog](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html), Apple has fixed this in XCode 6.3.1. If this issue still bugs you, you might want to upgrade your environment.

Answer (score 0):

check that the deployment target for your app is not newer than the iOS version on the device.

Answer (score 0):

Your iOS device version is lower than the iOS version defined your application.

Ex. Suppose your device's iOS version is 7.1 and your App's target version is 8.0. So Device is shown as ineligible device.

You can fix the problem either by downgrade the target version of your App or Update your device.
[See picture for deployment target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M58Qk.png)

Comment: I guess if device OS version is higher than the OS supported by the Xcode, then Xcode display as Ineligible Devices

Comment: If your Xcode is not updated then it will not support the latest OS release, so the device is not eligible to test