# iPhone becomes ineligible device in Xcode 7 beta2 after upgraded to iOS 8.4

Tags: ios, xcode

So I'm doing test on my iPhone 6 and everything works just fine with iOS 8.3. After upgrading to 8.4 my device became unavailable. Does anyone know why??

Comment: Try replugging in the device a few times.

Comment: I solved the same isue using following links.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24039010/ineligible-devices-section-appeared-in-xcode-6-x-x

Comment: nothing worked for me. any luck @KingJ?

Comment: @dreamlab check my own answer below

Comment: Xcode 7 Beta 4 is released now which fixes this issue

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Just found out the solution:

1. Download Xcode 6.4
2. Go to its content directory: /Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport
3. Copy folder "8.4 (12H141)" which contains the device support to the same path of Xcode 7 beta and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

you also need to change the deployment target to 8.4, as by default the version is 9 in Xcode 7 beta