# The Developer Disk image could not be mounted error with iOS 8.4 device - Ineligible Devices section

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8.4, xcode6.3.1

I have tried with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24039010/ineligible-devices-section-appeared-in-xcode-6-x-x) but couldn't solve my issue - Ineligible Devices section.

I m getting an error **The Developer Disk image could not be mounted error with iOS 8.4 device**

can anyone please help me how can I run iOS 8.4 version device with Xcode 6.3.1

or updating the Xcode version is only the solution

Thank you all in advance

[image]

Comment: This helps without updating http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35024975/is-there-a-way-to-test-my-xcode-7-2-compiled-app-with-ios-9-3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to upgrade to Xcode 6.4 in order to support iOS 8.4 development -

From the [Xcode 6.4 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc6_release_notes.html) -

> **New Features**
>
> - Xcode 6.4 includes the iOS 8.4 SDK to support development
>     for iOS 8.4 apps.