# Trying to get the xcode project from mac to run on iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I need some configuration help with getting the xcode project from mac to run on my iphone.

My Mac OS version - 10.9.5
I tried Xcode versions , 5.1.1 and 6.1.1 (beyond this version is not supported by my mac OS)

Device Iphone - 5
OS on IPhone - 9.3.2

Seems like the xcode versions are not compatible with iphone os 9.3.2.

Comment: There is no work-around.

Comment: you could try to run on virtual machine with the latest mac os

Comment: There are a few things to try. You can't just run the app on the device from Xcode, but there are probably a bunch of ways to get app onto the device. You can try the "Devices" window in Xcode (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/35044362/1271826). Or go old school, and bypass Xcode entirely. If you search Stack Overflow for "[ios] install app without xcode", you'll probably see lots of Q&A on the topic.

Comment: Thanks all for your responses..                                                                           Rob... I have tried the Devices option and that is where I was getting the compatibility issue.. Instead of the simulators, I connected my iphone to the mac and tried to use that as the device. I will try to check the other option you suggested about installing without xcode

Answer (score 0):

You need to first update your MAC OS to El Capitan and also need Xcode 7.3.

If you having before iPhone iOS version like < 8.0 it will work with this Xcode.

**Reason: Xcode 7.3 having iOS 9.3 or later iOS version support**