# Device Support files (iOS 14) for Xcode11

Tags: ios, xcode

I just update my iPhone to iOS 14 beta, does anybody have the iOS 14 device support files for Xcode?
I'm using Xcode 11.

Comment: Please use Xcode 12 for iOS 14 support.

Comment: If you’ve upgraded your device to iOS 14 beta and want to run app built from Xcode 11, you’d have to manually install it, like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35044362/1271826) (or via TestFlight or other similar mechanism). But you won’t be able to run it from the debugger in Xcode 11 anymore.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can actually add device support files from a future Xcode version on your current Xcode Version. This PR adds the file to a very popular GitHub repo that hosts these device support files: https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/pull/110

Comment: I prefer not to copy these files from this location, however you can download Xcode12, unzip it and copy the files from there into the location specified in the above pull request. Upvoted.

Comment: In a sense you are right. But sometimes internet connection speeds are rubbish and this repo has personally saved me from spending many hours from downloading 7+ gigabytes of Xcode beta versions.

Comment: I know what you mean, my main internet is Satellite.

Comment: xcode11.3.1 + iPhone iOS 14.2 + Support file = Work great!

Comment: Xcode 11.2.1 + iOS 14.3 + copied support files + restarted both phone and Mac but getting an "Unable to copy symbols from this device" error message in XCode when trying to run my application :( Has anyone seen this?

Comment: This worked for me but it seems like remote debugging isn't working. I guess I can use the simulator to fill the gap. I can compile the app and install it on an iPhone running iOS 14.3 from a MacBook running macOS 10.14.6 and Xcode 11.7 but I can't run the app in the debugger. I fully expect this setup to break in subtle ways but I don't care. I really don't want to "upgrade" to Big Sur. All of this because I accidentally "upgraded" my phone to iOS 14.

Comment: Is anyone else having trouble with Xcode 12?

This always used to work for me. But since Xcode 12, copying the device support files (right now trying to get iOS 14.4.1 into Xcode 12.2) still gets me stuck on the "Device is not available" thing.

Comment: I had some issues with this solution. Please check out my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68776409/xcode-11-ios-14-and-32-bit-apps

Answer (score 4):

Add Device Support files in Xcode. You can download device support files from here: https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/tree/master/DeviceSupport,
Open Application right click on Xcode and click on show package contents and contents/Developer/platform/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport and paste in this folder then restart your Xcode and Enjoy

Comment: For iOS14, restarting the device is required

Comment: @CHAKRI, as in the device I'm trying to debug?

Comment: @CHAKRI we have to restart our Xcode only

Comment: Restarting XCode seems to leave us in a state where it's still building for iOS 13.X, not 14.0, even after copying the 14.0 DEvice Support files over. Is there a way to make it build for 14.0?  I want to compile just a 14.0 version (so that the app store will accept it), how do I do that after copying the device support files into XCode 11? @vittalpai

Comment: Please check out my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68776409/xcode-11-ios-14-and-32-bit-apps

Answer (score 4):

Follow the below steps in order to iOS 14 apps on Xcode 11 or earlier

- Download iOS 14 support files from this link :
  https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport
- Quit Xcode
- Unzip the downloaded file in the following location:
  `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/` and paste the unzipped file
- Reopen Xcode and it works :)

Comment: I had some issues with this solution. Please check out my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68776409/xcode-11-ios-14-and-32-bit-apps

Answer (score 3):

It is more likely that **it is not possible to connect mobile device with iOS 14 on Xcode version <= 12**

As it is mentioned [here](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/issues/109#issuecomment-694671957) according to [xcode-12-release-notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-12-release-notes)

> Xcode 12 now encrypts the connection between Xcode and paired devices, protecting against an attacker in a privileged network position executing arbitrary code on connected iOS, iPadOS, watchOS, or tvOS devices during a remote debug session. (60386733)

> These security benefits are available when Xcode 12 connects to devices running iOS 14, iPadOS 14, watchOS 7, tvOS 14, or later versions. **These OS versions also refuse debugger connections from older Xcode releases.** Xcode 12 continues to support debugging for older OS versions, but without the new encryption.

Apple also gives some recommendations:

> If you’re unable to upgrade to Xcode 12 or need to continue development on devices running older OS versions, you can help protect yourself with either of the following measures:
>
> Connect Xcode to your devices over private and secured networks (including a direct connection);
>
> or
> Physically connect your device to the Mac running Xcode using a cable, and ensure that the “Connect via Network” checkbox in the Xcode Devices and Simulators Window is unselected for these devices.

but they hardly helps

Comment: Yes, guys. DeviceSupport didn't help for this moment.

Comment: no the DeviceSupport works, just make sure that you restart your device as a final step

Answer (score 1):

For iOS 14.7 device support file, you can make copy of Device support of iOS 14.6 and rename it for 14.7 I am using it in XCode 12.4 and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in 3 simple steps

1. Download and install Xcode 12
2. Copy the folder named 14.0 from your new Xcode app to your 11 Xcode app. You can found it in this path `/Applications/[Xcode-12|11-beta.app]/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport` ([Xcode-11|12] your Xcode folder name)
3. Unplug and plug your phone and restart your 11 Xcode

Apply for other Xcode and OS versions.

Comment: I had some issues with this solution. Please check out my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68776409/xcode-11-ios-14-and-32-bit-apps

Answer (score 0):

If you still have any problem after adding the device support files, checkout the article below. It worked for me.

https://medium.com/better-programming/debugging-on-ios-14-with-xcode-11-d332f12f49dd