# Xcode - physical iOS - unsupported OS version (iOS 16) (cannot launch on real device)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, react-native, ios16

After updating OS version on my iPhone to iOS 16, I got message in Xcode telling that the version install on the physical device is unsupported, hence I cannot launch the app on that device :(

Comment: update xcode and macos.

Comment: Looks like question has near duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67863355/xcode-12-4-unsupported-os-version-after-iphone-ios-update-14-7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hadn't have my **Xcode** updated. This is what I had to do:

1. Go to **AppStore**
2. Search for **Xcode**
3. Click on **Update**

In case you cannot launch properly a simulator from the previous versions, or it doesn't exist after updating Xcode, then, in the opened Xcode do next:

1. click on **simulator icon** (top-middle)
2. press on **Add Additional Simulators**
3. give a name to your new simulator and choose one from the list
   Hope that works for you as well)

Answer (score 22):

If you are using older xCode then **Xcode14.0** (i have Xcode13.2.1) then follow below steps:

Download the device support file from:
https://github.com/filsv/iOSDeviceSupport

Unzip it and put it the folder to path:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/

Now you need to hit and try the bellow actions(it depends some devs are lucky enough to run it on first try, not like me :) ) to run the App:

**1:** Quit Xcode, clean and build.

**2:** Add device component, this process will work automatically when you connect your device via cable, but **in case it fails you need to restart your mac once**.

**3:** From iPhone turn on Developer mode **"Setting > privacy & security"** and restart iPhone one's(**IOS 16 only**)

**Last one for who are facing** **"iphone-is-busy-preparing-debugger-support-for-iphone"** **-->**

Disconnect device, Go to **Xcode> devices and Simulator>** , click on **Plus(+)** button on bottom left corner. complete the steps by clicking Next and complete the device setup process.

Comment: Nice one. Thank you for the ios Device support zip file.

Comment: Great tutorial! The "reboot" in step 2 was required for me.