# Xcode iOS app build for newest iPhone (How to make Xcode to deploy to the very latest iOS without updating Xcode?)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

There MacBook with MacOS Catalina 10.15.7, that I don't want to upgrade to macOS 11. Maybe macOS 12 in 2022, after all small bugs there will be fixed and polished.

I could check for exact Xcode version support from https://xcodereleases.com/ (as the latest Xcode require macOS 11 since Xcode 12.5 26 Apr 2021). So I downloaded Xcode 12.4

Now there problem is that there is iPhone with the newest iOS 14.5:
Xcode can see it, but refuses to deploy my iOS app, saying that that version is not supported. (But it work with iOS 14 emulator)

Well, I totally agree that to use newest feature on newest device a developer must have newest Xcode, but I don't need that. I just hope to compile with target for iOS 13-14 and be able to deploy even to the latest isOS 14-15 device.

**How to make Xcode to deploy to the very latest iOS without updating Xcode?**

Answer (score -1):

Download specific DeviceSupport zip file from https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport
and unzip content to
`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport`

- [Xcode 12.4 “Unsupported OS version” after iPhone iOS update 14.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67863355/xcode-12-4-unsupported-os-version-after-iphone-ios-update-14-6)
- [Device Support files (iOS 14) for Xcode11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62526772/device-support-files-ios-14-for-xcode11?noredirect=1&lq=1)