# iPhone unavailable from Xcode Version 7.0 (7A220)

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

I just updated my Xcode to Version 7.0 (7A220) and out of the blue I got this message when I connect my iPhone to xCODE to test an application :

```
iPhone from nuñito (unavailable)
```

and everything is fine from iTunes !

I've tried all these solutions !
[Ineligible Devices section appeared in Xcode 6.x.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24039010/ineligible-devices-section-appeared-in-xcode-6-x-x/29538173#29538173)

iOS version in my phone running -> **iOS 9.1**

iOS version in my app's deployment target –> **9.0**

Comment: What iOS version is your phone running?  What iOS version is your app's deployment target?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update to Xcode 7.1 to use iOS 9.1, this should resolve this issue.

If I'm not mistaken, Xcode 7.0 doesn't support iOS 9.1, so device is "unavailable".

Comment: I've chnanged the deployment target to 8.0 with the same result :-(

Comment: @NuñitodelaCalzada, It's not the problem of deployment target, it's that Xcode 7.0 doesn't know about iOS 9.1, so device is "unavailable".