# Xcode: i am using xcode 7.0 and it shows iphone device shows "unavailable"?

Tags: ios, xcode7

I am using xcode 7.0, when i connect my iPhone device to xcode, it is showing that device is unavailable. My iPhone iOS version is 9.2.

Comment: Maybe the reason is hidden in one of the 151 issues ;-)

Comment: Make sure you clicked on "trust this computer" on your iPhone

Comment: @vadian - No, I checked already.

Comment: @gusta - i did it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ineligible Devices section appeared in Xcode 6.x.x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24039010/ineligible-devices-section-appeared-in-xcode-6-x-x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have an Xcode in version 7.2 or higher to run device with iOS 9.2.

Comment: You may be right but after clicking on update not able to update Xcode 7.2 or higher. It shows buffering symbol for long time but not progress in updating Xcode.

Comment: Did you use the Appstore to install the update? Sometimes it doesn't work. Ex. I   had an Xcode 7.2 and wanted to install 7.3. I used an Appstore, everything had seemed do proceed correctly but as a result I had: not updated Xcode (still 7.2.x) and an "Open" label by the Xcode icon on the Appstore (not "Update"). The solution was downloading the Xcode from developer.apple.com.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer in the below link.

[Ineligible Devices section appeared in Xcode 6.x.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24039010/ineligible-devices-section-appeared-in-xcode-6-x-x?lq=1)

As @Aleksandra you need to use xcode 7.2.