# xcode 8,ios 10 beta very annoying bug(?): "os version lower than deployment target"

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8, ios10

So.. I have downloaded xcode 8 and than installed ios 10 beta by using the configuration profile as advised in apple developer website.the install was successful and I can see the current ios 10 version in my device settings.
my problem:

Trying to run an ios 10 code (wwdc 2016 sample) I get an immediate response (before even click on the run button): "os version lower than deployment target". when I hit the run button I get:"the run destination device is not valid for running the scheme.." error.

Tried and failed:

Quit xcode,reopening everything including the imac itself,itunes,xcode and iphone.if I had hairs on my head i would have loose them by now.
would be happy for any help,
thanks!

- I have noticed itunes also does not recognise the change in the ios version although device itself is recognised. still cannot find any solution.

Comment: This is a very chaotic question. 1. On what destination device did you try to run it? On the top left, next to `run` button, you have your target. Did you try to do it on your real iPhone/iPad device or on simulator? 2. Did you try to clear derived data & relaunch Xcode? 3. What devices does your app support and on what device do you try to run it? BTW: it's good to use capital letters, other people can read the question easier.

Comment: your remark is a bit unfair.I have told that the ios 10 beta install was a success and therefore the device is not a simulator.if it is important it's an iphone 6s plus but why it is important to the question? also i have told that the "os version lower than deployment target" is a remark before i even run the app so its not relevant which device the app supports.i do however except your last remark.

Comment: 1. I didn't downvote the question. 2. I didn't ask what is your device but IF you run on simulator or on real device - your device type, exactly as you think, doesn't matter. 3. You could install new iOS but you could not select to run app on the device and you're running by default on simulator, so yea, I think that's still a valid question. 4. Once again: can check your target settings: what is your deployment target? 5. We're trying to help, it's irrational to be mad that people ask questions to know more about your situation to be able to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Set the deployment target lower in Xcode
Use a device that matches the deployment target in the project.
OR
[Check This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24039010/ineligible-devices-section-appeared-in-xcode-6-x-x)

Comment: Thanks,i have done both.the deployment target on xcode is ios 10.the device itself has an ios beta version. itunes and xcode do not recognize the ios 10 install and show ios 9.3.2

Comment: Create a simulator with the required target OS and use that to deploy