# XCode6 not enabling development on iOS8 iPhone device

Tags: usb, ios8, xcode-organizer, xcode6-beta5

I realise this is a duplicate of a few other questions:


[Ineligible Devices section appeared in Xcode 6.x.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24039010/xcode6-ineligible-devices-section-appeared)

[Xcode 6 won't let me develop on my iOS 8 phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024460/xcode-6-wont-let-me-develop-on-my-ios-8-phone)

But I'm hoping to provide more detail.

Different messages appear at different times in the System Console, when this error occurs:

> 18/08/14 2:46:22.000 am kernel[0]: USB (XHCI Root Hub USB 2.0
>   Simulation):Port 1 on bus 0xa connected or disconnected:
>   portSC(0xe0206e1) 
> 18/08/14 2:46:24.827 am Xcode[300]:
>   stream_image (thread 0x1131f5000): received ack: ReceiveBytesAck,
>   proceeding with transfer... 
> 18/08/14 2:46:24.830 am
>   com.apple.usbmuxd[47]: MuxTCPInputSCE received RST for
>   0x1-5448ce54615fa3fcc36079423e0fde3c403d1615@0x14100000:49230->0x100312220-Xcode/com.apple.dt.Xcode:10752:
>   handleMuxTCPInput no matching session 
> 18/08/14 2:46:24.830 am
>   com.apple.usbmuxd[47]: MuxTCPInputSCE received RST for
>   0x1-5448ce54615fa3fcc36079423e0fde3c403d1615@0x14100000:49230->0x100312220-Xcode/com.apple.dt.Xcode:10752:
>   handleMuxTCPInput no matching session 
> 18/08/14 2:46:24.831 am
>   com.apple.usbmuxd[47]: MuxTCPInputSCE received RST for
>   0x1-5448ce54615fa3fcc36079423e0fde3c403d1615@0x14100000:49230->0x100312220-Xcode/com.apple.dt.Xcode:10752:
>   handleMuxTCPInput no matching session 
> 18/08/14 2:46:24.831 am
>   Xcode[300]: __stream_image_block_invoke (thread 0x1131f5000):
>   AMDServiceConnectionSend failed: 0xe800002d, kAMDSendMessageError,
>   buflen: 65536, sent: -1 
> 18/08/14 2:46:24.831 am Xcode[300]:
>   stream_image (thread 0x1131f5000): read_file failed 
> 18/08/14
>   2:46:24.831 am Xcode[300]: AMDeviceMountImage (thread 0x1131f5000):
>   stream_image failed (kAMDSendMessageError), trying copy...
>   
> 18/08/14 2:46:24.831 am Xcode[300]: copy_image (thread
>   0x1131f5000): Jay Root 
> 18/08/14 2:46:27.365 am Xcode[300]:
>   AMDeviceMountImage (thread 0x1131f5000): line: 207: Could not hangup
>   with service agent: kAMDSendMessageError 
> 18/08/14 2:46:27.454 am
>   Xcode[300]: mount_image (thread 0x1131f5000): There was an error
>   mounting the image: kAMDSuccess 
> 18/08/14 2:46:27.455 am
>   Xcode[300]: AMDeviceMountImage (thread 0x1131f5000): Could not mount
>   image: kAMDMobileImageMounterMissingImagePath 
> 18/08/14
>   2:46:27.456 am Xcode[300]: AMDeviceMountImage (thread 0x1131f5000):
>   Could not hangup with service agent: kAMDSendMessageError

These occur simultaneously with the following errors from the iPhone logs:

> Aug 18 03:05:55 iPhone mobile_storage_proxy[145] :
>   0x34ae59cc handle_receive_bytes: The request is missing the disk image
>   signature 
> Aug 18 03:05:55 iPhone mobile_storage_proxy[145]
>   : 0x34ae59cc handle_receive_bytes: failed, unlinking  
> Aug
>   18 03:05:55 iPhone mobile_storage_proxy[145] : 0x34ae59cc main:
>   Could not receive bytes 
> Aug 18 03:05:55 iPhone
>   mobile_storage_proxy[146] : 0x34ae59cc handle_mount_image:
>   Could not find disk image 
> Aug 18 03:05:55 iPhone
>   mobile_storage_proxy[146] : 0x34ae59cc main: Could not mount
>   the image

Note: Timestamp is off in the above logs because I copied the iPhone logs from a different test-run.

Other times, this error is preceded by another USB-related error message in the OSX logs:

> 18/08/14 1:37:58.824 am com.apple.usbmuxd[47]: MuxClearPipeStall Can't clear pipe stall 2 on 0x4-5448ce54615fa3fcc36079423e0fde3c403d1615@0x14200000. Error: 0xe00002c0

The above message ALSO being common to some [generic iTunes sync issues](https://discussions.apple.com/message/9655871#9655871) encountered [very long ago](https://discussions.apple.com/message/9808946#9808946) by some users

Restarting XCode, the iPhone, the Mac over and over and reconnecting the device in different orders (while the Mac is starting up. Before XCode is launched. After XCode is launched, etc.) has not helped.

Resetting the PRAM and SMC (a couple different procedures [here](http://www.ehow.com/how_7351075_reset-usb-ports-mac-laptops.html) and [here](http://macs.about.com/od/usingyourmac/qt/Resetting-The-Smc-System-Management-Controller-On-Your-Mac.htm)) have not helped either.

#### Can someone understand the root of the issue from the above logs? And if so, suggest a more permanent solution?

(than restarting X device or performing some timing voodoo).

Comment: I also encountering this "ineligible" issue and didn't succeed to solve it yet

Comment: Has anyone solved it.I am also stuck there.

Comment: This error was occurring for me in XCode6-Beta5. Upgrading to XCode6-Beta7 solved it for me. I know that may not help, but so far it's the only thing that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just got it after logging out and back in to iCloud.

Rebooted device - didn't help.
Rebooted Mac AND device - didn't help.
Replugged to a different USB port - didn't help.
Finally, relaunched Xcode - works.

Spent about 15-30 mins with this. Some stupid bug, one of millions.

P.S. Xcode 6.0.1, iOS 8.0, iPhone 5S

Comment: Precisely why I'm hoping someone can provide a long-term answer to this. So many ways to trigger it and so many random solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what actually worked for me:

1. unplug all devices that you're developing with.
2. quit XCode
3. I rebuilt my .xcodeproj file - easy because I'm using cordova
4. start XCode (now, at least I have all the simulators listed)
5. plug your device back in

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I'm looking - if possible - for a permanent, broad-based answer, based on an understanding of the root issue. Quote - "Can someone understand the root of the issue from the above logs? And if so, suggest a more permanent solution?" Without an explanation or some kind of analysis of the root issue, any answer to this question would be incomplete.

Comment: Just tried this solution out on my own Cordova project and am still seeing my phone under ineligible devices. Bummer.

Answer (score -1):

Please use **Xcode 6.1**

Xcode 6 only contains the iOS 8.0 SDK.
If you're running iOS 8.1 on your phone, then you'll need to upgrade to Xcode 6.1, which contains the iOS 8.1 SDK.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I'm looking - if possible - for a permanent, broad-based answer, based on an understanding of the root issue. Quote - "Can someone understand the root of the issue from the above logs? And if so, suggest a more permanent solution?" Without an explanation or some kind of analysis of the root issue, any answer to this question would be incomplete. As a comment, yes, this could be useful for anyone else encountering this issue and visiting this question.

Comment: Here is some info that might help to find a root cause. These symptoms happened to me on a beta XCode 7.1 (IOS 9.1) after plugging in the new S6. I dropped back to 7.0 plugged in the phone and XCode downloaded and processed 'Symbol Files' for the phone. This clearly was not happening in XCode 7.1 for the iPhone 6S. The phone then was availabe for debugging. This is probably why the other answers of 'plug out/in' the phone might work.