# Ineligible Devices - xcode 6

Tags: iphone, ios8, xcode6

My device isn't working with the xcode (6).

I've installed the iOS 8 beta on my device and tried to run my app via the xcode 6 on the device, but unfortunately my device appears under "Ineligible Devices" section.

I also bumped with the following links:
[Xcode 6 won't let me develop on my iOS 8 phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024460/xcode-6-wont-let-me-develop-on-my-ios-8-phone)
[Ineligible Devices section appeared in Xcode 6.x.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24039010/xcode6-ineligible-devices-section-appeared)

But the actions there didn't help me, any other actions to do other than changing the "Deployment target" + restart (xcode/mac/device)?

Comment: are you using Apple's original USB charger?

Comment: Which beta version of Xcode do you have and which version of iOS 8 beta are you running?

Comment: @holex I'm using the original USB

Comment: @rckoenes I'm using the xcode 6 beta 6 and ios 8 beta 5

Comment: @TomerPeled, then _beta6_ vs _beta5_ is your problem here.

Comment: @holex I don't think so... I tried the same with xcode beta 5 and ios 8 beta 5 and it didn't work also. So I've updated my xcode to beta 6, hoping that this will solve my problem, but the problem still exists. Also  there is still not ios 8 beta 6...

Comment: @TomerPeled, that is true, there is no iOS8 SDK beta6 yet.

Answer (score 20):

In my case, selecting the device from Product -> Destination worked great.

Comment: This worked for me as well, after doing this XCode gave me the prompt to fix the code signing issues and that resolved it.

Answer (score 4):

After re-connecting in XCode 6.1. It's working fine. Please try again.

Comment: Works by reconnecting the device in XCode 6.1

Comment: You deserve more upvotes! It works when disconnecting/reconnecting the Apple ID from Xcode.

Answer (score 3):

We have to wait to Xcode 6.1, it should be uploaded yesterday but link doen´s work well

Xcode 6.1:
    Posted: Oct 16, 2014
    Build: 6A1052c
    Included iOS SDK: iOS 8.1
    Included Mac SDK: OS X v10.10

Answer (score 0):

Disconnect device and clean Xcode 6.1. Reconnect device. This worked for me.

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Answer (score 0):

Confirm when connect your device (iOS 8.1 and Xcode6.1) unlocked , it will show as ineligible device even after unlock the device,

so next time you will connect as unlocked device so reconnect clear that issue. i hope it may help to some one.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Xcode 6.1, iOS 8.2) I did not see any updates in AppStore.
I found Xcode 6.2 for download and pressed "Install". It installed and asked for the update (more than 2 Gb).

Xcode 6.2 works correctly with iOS 8.2 and iOS 8.1.2

Hopefully this tip will help somebody else...

Answer (score 0):

Your project is configured for an iOS version higher than your device. Update your device or change the iOS Deployment Target on Targets->[Your project]->Build Settings->Deployment-> iOS Deployment Target